# Ionic focus input on click - keyboard overlaps and doesn't focus input

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When I click on an input within the ionic app with the markup either ion-item or input, the keyboard overlaps and doesn't focus.

What is the easiest way to have focus on all inputs by default? Or just get it to focus on click.

```
<ion-item> 
    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<input class="round-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email2" required  />
```

the following works for ios for ionic-input but not android.

```
.input-cover {
  position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it this way which works reasonably.

```
this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(e => {

console.log('Keyboard height is: ' + e.keyboardHeight);

jQuery('body').animate({ 'marginTop': - e.keyboardHeight + 'px' }, 200);

});

this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(e => {

jQuery('body').animate({ 'marginTop': 0 + 'px' }, 200);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//add this on a controller on which you want to focus a filed
var input = this;
    input.focus = function () {
        document.getElementById('input').focus();
     };
```

```html
<form name="loginform" novalidate>
    <div class="login-form ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" ng-init="input.focus();">
                <span class="icon-login"> <i class="icon ion-person placeholder-icon"></i></span>
                   <input type="email" id="email_address" placeholder="Email Address" name="email_address" ng-model="data.email_address" focus-me autofocus/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <span class="icon-login"><i class="icon ion-locked placeholder-icon"></i></span>
                    <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="password"  ng-model="data.password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit"  ng-click="login()" class="button button-light text-uppercase Avenir-Medium text-blue margintp10">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```